# Inline-block div's centered

Tags: html, css

I am coding for a few years now but currently got into CSS, the problem I'm currently having is the following: I want to put 2 div's next to each other but also center them, the codes I'm currently using:

HTML:

```
<div class="sidebar">Placeholder</div><div class="content">Placeholder</div>
```

CSS:

```
.sidebar { 
width: 223px; 
height: auto;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
}
.content {
width: 689px;
height: auto;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
}
```

Who can help me with this problem? ;)

Comment: Do you want to center them vertically or horizontally? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you want responsive too ?

Comment: A jsfiddle for the dude's stuff..  [http://jsfiddle.net/x9F8J/](http://jsfiddle.net/x9F8J/)                                                                PS - Welcome to SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the elements in a container, and give it text-align: center.

http://jsfiddle.net/q8tKP/ :

```
.container {
    text-align: center;
}

.sidebar, .content {
    display: inline-block;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here: **Fiddle** : http://jsfiddle.net/3MvVK/1/

```
<div id="wrapper"><div class="sidebar">Placeholder</div><div class="content">Placeholder</div></div>
```

CSS:

```
 #wrapper{
   display:table;
 }

 .sidebar, .content { 
    display: table-cell;
 }
```

If you want text center aligned too. Add `text-align:center;` to  `.sidebar, .content`

Comment: @JohnBupit just place margin: auto; at the wrapper style :P

Answer (score 0):

Add text-align: center to the container of both elements

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">Placeholder</div><div class="content">Placeholder</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="sidebar">Placeholder</div><div class="content">Placeholder</div>
</div>



.sidebar { 
width: 223px; 
height: auto;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
margin-right: 20px;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
    float:left;

}
.content {
width: 689px;
height: auto;
background-color: #E9E9E9;
border-radius: 5px;
border: 1px solid #7F7F7F;
box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px #FDFDFD;
box-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #949494;
padding: 5px;
display: inline-block;
margin: auto;
    float:left;

}
.container{ margin:0 auto; 
            width:936px;
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help you:

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>
            Two columns
        </title>
        <style>
        #body{
            width: 800px;
            margin: auto;
        }
        #header{
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
        }
        #footer{
            height: 50px;
            text-align: center;
            clear: both;
        }
        .left{
            float: left;
            width: 49%;
            position: relative;
        }
        .right{
            float: right;
            width: 49%;
            position: relative;
        }
        div{
            border: 1px solid black;
        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="body">
            <div id="header">
                HEADER
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                LEFT
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                RIGHT
            </div>
            <div id="footer">
                FOOTER
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```